# literature.bib problem

Tags: bibtex

I'm using a .bib file for my bibliography. It worked just fine til now.

Now I wanted to add the following literature:

```
@BOOK{datenqualität,
    author = {Treiblmaier, H.},
    title = {Datenqualität und individualisierte Kommunikation},
    publisher = {Deutscher Universitäts-Verlag},
    year = {2006},
    volume = {1. Auflage},
    pages = {19,20},
    isbn = {978-3-8350-0189-3}
}
```

Now if I compile the literature is neither shown in the .bbl nor in the latex. The reference \cite{datenqualität} shows a non linked [?]

I'm not sure why it doesnt work. I also have another literature:

```
@BOOK{EvaluationByBortz,
    author = {Bortz, J. and Döring, N},
    title = {Forschungsmethoden und Evaluationen für Human- und Sozialwissenschaftler},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year = {2002},
    volume = {4. Auflage},
    pages = {96},
    isbn = {978-3-540-33305-0}
}
```

and this one is shown and working fine.

Comment: How did you compile your document? Did you receive any error messages/warnings? Does it work if you change the key to "datenqualitaet" instead of "datenqualität"?

Comment: hm yeah, that did the trick. weird. I also have "ä", "ö" and "ü" in other literatures. Hm ... but not in the key. seems that its not allowed there.

Comment: @Danny - accented characters are allowed if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but not in pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `volume = {1. Auflage}`, you should use `edition = {1.}` and (probably) load the `babelbib` package with suitable options so that the edition field will be rendered as "1. Aufl.". An example of "suitable options" might be `\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib} \selectbiblanguage{german} \bibliographystyle{bababbrv}` if you wish to generate numeric-style citation call-outs.

Comment: `datenqualität` and `EvaluationByBortz` are internal keys/names for your entries. Those internal names need to conform to slightly different requirements than printed text and printable input. With engines that are not Unicode aware it is probably safer to stick with US-ASCII characters for those internal names. (If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you should be able to use all Unicode characters here.)